# How to use subversion's propset against a URL?

Tags: svn, svn-externals, svn-propset

Is it possible to manipulate a subversion property such as `svn:externals` via a URL only?  (i.e. without having a working copy.)

I'd like a script that pins `svn:externals` to a particular revision given a subversion URL, but this seems to be impossible:

```
$ svn propset foo bar https://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk
svn: Setting property on non-local target 'https://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk' needs a base revision

$ svn propset foo bar -r HEAD https://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Cannot specify revision for setting versioned property 'foo'

$ svn propset foo bar --revprop -r HEAD https://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk
svn: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svn: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svn: Error setting property 'foo': 
could not remove a property
```

(I get the same results if I use an actual revision number instead of `HEAD` as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Changing a property on a file is like changing the file itself -- you need a working directory. There are a few Subversion commands that change the commit without requiring a working copy: `svn cp`, `svn mkdir`, and `svn delete`. Everything else needs a working directory in order to make changes.

By the way, you can make changes on ***revision*** properties without a working copy. Revision properties are things like the commit comment (svn:log), the committer's ID (svn:author), and the time of the commit (svn:date).

Comment: A workaround seems to be to `svn checkout --depth=empty` into a temporary directory with `mktemp` or similar (this is fairly fast), use `svn propset` to make the change, commit, and then remove the temporary directory.

Comment: There is another option: svnmucc, which is included with SVN sources but not built or installed by default.  You can read about it at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html.

Comment: Adding to note by @trent, TortoiseSVN is now bundling svnmucc with installer as of version 1.8.1 and newer https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/tickets/496/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, although it's a bit of a hack; svn propedit can change URL targets:

`svn propedit foo --editor-cmd "echo bar>" http://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk -m "Property changed"`

Comment: that's a great trick but it's better to specify the message in commandline via `-m` flag otherwise the editor will be invoked for the message too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`svnmucc`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html) command to non-interactively set properties of an URL such as `svn:externals`.

Example:

```
$ svnmucc --root-url https://example.com/svn -m 'reference other/yap' \
   propset svn:externals "^/otherproject/tag/xyz other
^/yetanother/tag/123 yap" myproject/trunk
```

Note that `svnmucc` also supports other commands besides `propset` and it is possible to chain multiple commands in one call (hence the name). The result is just one changeset.

The `svnmucc` command is part of the subversion source package and usually available via the distribution's package manager. For example,  Fedora 25 includes it in the `subversion-tools` package. OpenCSW even includes it in the main subversion package.

Comment: Multi-line in windows is not allowed. command breaks after the first property. and  if I write it in continues single line it treats it as single property. whats the solution to run this command on windows?

Comment: @SahilDoshi I'm not a Windows user - but when I use Windows I install Cygwin and do such stuff in a Cygwin terminal. Since then you are in a standard shell (such as bash) you should be able to work with line continuations and multi line quoted strings like in a Linux/UNIX environment.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Willem's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954355/423045), here's an example showing how to set SVN `auto-props` for `needs-lock` for all files and `mime-type` for particular extensions using a URL:

```
svn propedit svn:auto-props --editor-cmd "echo \"* = svn:needs-lock=*
*.os = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream
*.osproj = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream\" >" http://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk -m "Setting auto-props."
```